# RAM overflow with new Distance tools: Optimal Path as Line

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I have set up a workflow for least-cost path analysis using the legacy Distance tools of the Spatial Analyst. Trying to convert this into the new toolsets now, the new tool Distance Accumulation produces reasonable outputs and I can clearly see a difference from the legacy tools. However, the final step using Optimal Path as Line is using RAM cumulatively and after a couple of minutes, I am out of memory (32 GB...). I have tried to reduce the workload by just calculating one path, but that also fails due to "insufficient" memory.

Additionally, The output of Distance Accumulation produces a backlink raster with values 0-360 (degrees), whereas Optimal Path as Line demands 8-bit input (0-255). I rescaled it to get the tool moving in the first place.

These new tools feel pretty "alpha", hope someone can share some experiences and workarounds.
Just for some more context, I have a workflow using the legacy tools which processes 1200 lines between 35 nodes in about 4 hours time and there are no memory issues.

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.7.

Comment: Deafening silence on this matter https://community.esri.com/t5/arcmap-questions/flaw-in-cost-distance-tool-arcgis-10-8/m-p/599154

Comment: Thanks for breaking the silence. I have submitted a bug report a few months on another matter to ESRI, and never heard back since. Is it worthwhile submitting the issue outlined above or not worth it from experience?

Comment: If only you have time. I tried a couple of times on different matters, couldn't get through to magic submit button. I found however that arcgis 10.8 does brilliant job with parallel processing 4 cores. Used to fail in 10.5